# How can I do a dependent entity read only without losing the foreign key in EF core 2.0?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to make BlogId and Blog read-only without losing BlogId as a foreign key. How can I achieve this in EF Core 2.0?

```
    public class Blog
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Post
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
    
        private int _blogId;
        public int BlogId =>_blogId;

        //I want this entity to be read-only without loose the foreign key             
        //in the database 
        public Blog Blog { get; set; }
    }
    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)        
    {
       modelBuilder.Property<int>("BlogId").HasField("_blogId");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `Blog` property's set accessor `protected`

`public Blog Blog { get; protected set; }`

Comment: thanks this worked fine. Just wondering, is there another way without having property "set" at all?

Comment: @lgarcia11 EF needs to set the value of the property when materializing database values so a `set` accessor is required.